# How should I keep the security key secret in a Windows environment for PCI compliance?

Tags: .net, key, storage

Anyway, I've decided to upgrade the security protocols at my place. And well, keeping that Master Key secret even from internal staff is tough. My goal is to make it as hard as I can for one person, inside the company or out, from breaking into the system and acquiring the key. And we need to acquire PCI DSS compliance.

We're running on Microsoft technology, so .NET and IIS, Windows, etc.

How the key gets generated is two custodians enter a pass phrase. The system then uses those to create the master key. The two custodians are never to share their phrase with each other, or any other person, and they have to sign a form saying such. If they write it down, it must be in a safe that only they have access to. The phrase also allows us to regenerate the key in case it gets lost. When the system gets rekeyed, new phrases are used and the process starts over.

I think we're OK there as far as security is concerned. My main issue is on the tech side, how to keep that Master Key secret as best I can, without buying a piece of hardware. The best I can come up with on that angle is to first encrypt the key using a key stored in a DLL. That helps keep the IT people from figuring it out, but I know this is the weakest link. Anyway, after it is encrypted from that, I am going to further encrypt it using DPAPI using machine-level mode. Then store it in the registry with some ACL protection. Those last two steps will help keep the programmers from deciphering it (they won't have access to Production), as well as help to keep intruders from deciphering it.

Whenever the key is in memory, it'll only be kept in memory for as long as needed, then killed. I'll use SecureString to keep it from being written to disk on a cache or dump or what not.

This process would also allow us to expand to a web farm relatively easily.

But it sounds like there is something glaring that I'm missing. Anything I should add or change or remove? Thanks a bunch!